# Unable to Find a matching Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In my Partial view when I go to call a controller method I get an error message unable to find matching controller, but if I am in a normal view I can call the controller using

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("mkadmin", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

and using an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: '@Url.Action("mkadmin", "Home")',
```

I need to post data from a DataTable that is on my partial view to my controller which is below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult mkadmin(string col)
{
    // do stuff        
}
```

I created the partial view without a model. Would this be causing me the problem?

```
@model IEnumerable<FutatillDataAnalytics.Models.RolesViewModel>

<table id="dataTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>         
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleNames)
            </th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>            
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleNames)
            </th>           
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Id)
                </td>              
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.RoleNames)
                </td>                
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="tab" style="float: right; padding-top:20px" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button id="btnMKAD" type="button" onclick="MakeAdmin()" class="btn btn-large btn-success " data-toggle="tab">Make Admin</button>
    <button type="button"onclick="RemoveAdmin()"  class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="tab">Remove Admin</button>    
</div>

<script>
        //DataTable
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                }]
            });

        //    //Table Row Selection
        //    $('#dataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        //    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            //} );

            // Single Row Selection
            $('#dataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                // get selected row data and retireve the data from col 1 which is hidden.
                var selected = (table.row(this).data());
                var col = selected[0];
               admin(col)

                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');

                }
                else {
                    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        });

        function admin(col) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("mkadmin", "Home")',
                data: { col },
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $('#byCustomer').html('<h3>Error in retrieval</h3>');
                }
            });
        };
</script>
```

Comment: how are you calling it in partial view ?, show that piece of code

Comment: We need more information so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: i added the partial view now @Ehsan Sajjad

Comment: ``doucment.ready()`` won't be called if partial view is loaded via ajax

Comment: Is the error happening when you click the table row or when you try to load the page?

Comment: Partial view isn't loaded via ajax

Comment: and javascript should not be written in partial views

Comment: Spivonious: when i click on the table row i want to get data from that which occurs but when it goes into the ajax call i get an error. internal server error 500. When i rightclick on the @url.action it tells me it cant find a matching controller

Comment: Your controller should be called HomeController. Is it?

Comment: Can you peek at the javascript and see what URL Razor put in there? I have a feeling the URL is incorrect.

Comment: Also, make sure the controller method is expecting your data parameter and allows the POST method.

Comment: Thanks Guys, i have it working now, the problem was with the url in my code i had a misspelling which i corrected when i wrote this post but never released that that was the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Spivonious, i have it working now, the problem was with the url in my code i had a misspelling which i corrected when i wrote this post but never released that that was the actual problem

Comment: Glad you got it working.